# Is there any way to force a schema to be respected?

Tags: mongodb, rdbms, nosql

First, I'd like to say that I really love `NoSQL` & `MongoDB` but I've got some major concerns with its `schema-less` aspect.

Let's say I have 2 tables. **Employees** and **Movies**.

And... I have a very stupid `data layer` / `framework` that sometimes like to save objects in the wrong tables.

So one day, a `Movie` gets saved in the `Employees` table. Like this:

```
> use mongoTests;
switched to db mongoTests
> db.employees.insert({ name : "Max Power", sex : "Male" });
> db.employees.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb25ce6420141116081ae57"), "name" : "Max Power", "sex" : "Male" }
> db.employees.insert({ title : "Fight Club", actors : [{ name : "Brad Pitt" }, { name : "Edward Norton" }]});
> db.employees.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb25ce6420141116081ae57"), "name" : "Max Power", "sex" : "Male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb25db834a31eb59101235b"), "title" : "Fight Club", "actors" : [ { "name" : "Brad Pitt" }, { "name" : "Edward Norton" } ] }
```

This is VERY wrong.

Let's switch the context, think about **Movies**, and **CreditCards** (for whatever reason, in this context credit cards would be stored in clear text inside the DB). This is SUPER WRONG?

1. The code would probably explode because it's trying to use an object
   structure and receives another totally unknown structure.
2. Even worst, the code actually works and the webstore visitors
   actually see credit cards information in the "Rent a movie" list.

Is there anything, built-in that would prevent such threat to ever happen? Like some way to "force" a schema to be respected for only some tables?

Or is there any way to force MongoDB to make a schema mandatory? (Can't create new fields in a table, etc)

***EDIT: For those who thinks I'm trolling, I'm really not, this is an important question for me and my team because this is a big decision whether or not we're going to use NoSQL.***

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Surely one thing to do is fix the bugs in the data layer.

Comment: @Pointy: Sure, but that doesn't fix the problem at its roots. Let's take in account that a developer may not have access to fix the data layer's bugs. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Another thing is to do not store personal informations in the same db used for "common" data (I would suggest a 2nd server too...). Then switch to another DB if (any kind of) security is important...

Comment: @Adriano: I wrote: "for whatever reason, in this context credit cards would be stored in clear text inside the DB" That should NEVER be done, but what if...? It's like saying oh never use MongoDB for important stuff! Why use two engines? Thanks

Comment: I'm not talking about credit card only but any personal information (even first/last name, address and so on). It depends on local laws but you may need to provide additional security for sensitive data (and for medical applications it may be imposed by the law to keep them separated). "It's like saying oh never use MongoDB for important stuff". Yes. It's like. You can't be 100% safe but less checks you have more you increase the probability to have errors.

Comment: @SeanReilly I'm really not trolling here. Let's say you use a data layer made my N company which you DO NOT have the sources and there's this huge security hole in it. There's nothing you can do about it, except shutdown the whole service. I'm just trying to figure if NoSQL engines are REALLY an alternative to RDBMS engines, and not only complementary. Thanks for the downvote by the way.

Comment: @fighting-it-morons Are you serious? I'm looking for constructiveness. I'm not saying "MongoDB sucks" damn it, I even precised that I love MongoDB.

Comment: This is a completely valid question. Even though this is a schema-less db, it's a good idea to know whether there are options to force some kind of schema in insert/update or not.

Comment: @TomShreds: either of the following two sections of the FAQ (under what questions *not* to ask) apply: a) we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
b) it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?” (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). IMO, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: now that question (even though this is a schema-less db, what are the options to force some kind of schema when inserting or updating) is an *excellent* question. I'd be happy to participate in that question if you asked it separately.

Comment: @SeanReilly This is a very valid argument, I may not follow the guidelines, that is not a reason for some to point me as a troll and say bad things about the question. I'll edit the question to be more specific. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema-less aspect is one of the major positives.

A DB with a schema doesn't fully remove this kind of issue - e.g. there could be a bug in a system that uses a RDBMS that puts the wrong data in the wrong field/table.

IMHO, the bigger concern would be, how did that kind of bug make it through dev, testing and out into production?!

Having said that, you could set up a process that checks the "schema" of documents within a collection (e.g. look at newly added documents, check whether they have fields you would expect to see in there) - then flag up for investigation. There is such a tool (node.js) here (I think, I've never used it):

http://dhendo.github.com/node-mongodb-schema-validator/

**Edit:**
For those finding this question in future, so the link in my comment doesn't go overlooked, there's a jira item for this kind of thing here: 
http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3536

Comment: "A DB with a schema doesn't fully remove this kind of issue - e.g. there could be a bug in a system that uses a RDBMS that puts the wrong data in the wrong field/table." Yes but, trying to add an unknown field to a table will gives you a "X field doesn't exist" error instead of inserting it.

Comment: I just find it kind of dumb that it's up to the developer to prevent that kind of stuff to happen. There should be some kind of "force schema" option or something... Thanks for replying!

Comment: @TomShreds - I hear what you're saying, yes it is to a lesser degree. I don't think it's dumb, after all - mongodb is giving a completely different option over RDBMS by solving other things in different ways and focusing on those differences. This jira issue for mongodb may be of interest with regard to this area... https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3536

Comment: Thanks for actually helping me, this is exactly what I'm talking about, it is really appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it runs in node, and you can feed it a set of expectations (e.g. every employee to have a name and sex field and an optional job title)

It will then pull you up on the movie, as it is not expecting to see a  "title" field or an actors array.

FYI, I would be wary of running it against a live DB, as per the warning on github :)

Comment: Weirdly enough, I haven't seen your link until now, maybe I was just being lunatic hehe, I think this is exactly what I was looking for!